Squeezing degredation via photon loss
Consider a partially reflecting beamsplitter with two input modes $\hat{a}_{in}$ and $\hat{b}_{in}$. It has a transmission coefficient of $\eta$. If the photon in mode $\hat{b}_{in}$ is in the vacuum state, then the output variance of a general quadrature for a photon in mode $\hat{a}_{in}$ is
$$\Delta \hat{X}_{\Theta,\text{out}}^2=\eta^2 \Delta \hat{X}_{\Theta,\text{in}}^2+(1-\eta^2)\frac{1}{4}$$
Now, I want to investigate how loss affects the squeezing. Squeezing in dB can be quantified by
$$S=10\log_{10}e^{2r}$$
where $e^{2r}$ is the squeezing parameter. Solving for this parameter, I get
$$e^{2r}=10^{S/10}$$
For 3dB of squeezing,
$$e^{2r}\approx2$$
If, for example, we're interested in the $\hat{X}_1$ quadrature, then the variance after squeezing should be
$$\Delta \hat{X}^2_{1,\text{out},\text{squeezed}}=e^{-2r}\Delta \hat{X}^2_{1,\text{out},\text{unsqueezed}}$$
So, the quadrature variance of $\hat{X}_{1,\text{out}}$ should be reduced by 1/2 after squeezing. In calculating $\Delta \hat{X}^2_{1,\text{out},\text{squeezed}}$, assume that $\eta=1$ and the input photon in mode $\hat{a}_{in}$ is a minimally uncertain state. So, $\Delta \hat{X}_{1,\text{in}}^2=1/4$. Hence,
$$\Delta \hat{X}^2_{1,\text{out},\text{squeezed}}=\frac{1}{2}\Delta \hat{X}^2_{1,\text{out},\text{unsqueezed}}=\frac{1}{8}$$
Now, suppose that there is a 50% loss in photons. So, let $\eta=1/\sqrt{2}$. Well, substituting this new $\eta$ into $\Delta \hat{X}^2_{1,\text{out},\text{squeezed}}$, I also get that $\Delta \hat{X}^2_{1,\text{out},\text{squeezed}}=1/8$... The effect of the squeezing should be lessened by the loss, meaning the reduction in the variance should be less than 1/2. Supposedly for 3dB squeezing following by 50% loss, the squeezing is reduced to roughly 1.33dB. But, that is not what my calculation shows here. Where might I have gone wrong here?

Under what conditions is your first equation valid?

It comes from representing the output quadratures as a superposition of the input quadratures. Then just compute the variance. Nominally, the output quadrature variance for a photon in mode-$\hat{a}$ is $\Delta \hat{X}{\Theta,a,\text{out}}^2=\eta^2\Delta\hat{X}{\Theta,a,\text{in}}^2+(1-\eta^2)\Delta\hat{X}{\Theta,b,\text{in}}^2$. $\eta$ is the transmission amplitude. $\sqrt{1-\eta^2}$ is the reflection amplitude. If the photon in mode-$\hat{b}$ is the vacuum, then $\Delta\hat{X}{\Theta,b,\text{in}}^2=1/4$ and you get the first equation.

OK, so what you should get is: amount of squeezing after loss = $\eta^2/4 \exp(-2r)+(1-\eta^2)/4$. Right? So for $\eta<1$ the second terms would increase the value, thus reducing the amount of squeezing.

How did you arrive at that expression? What quantity is that calculating?

Is that not what you would get when you compute $\langle\psi|\Delta \hat{X}^2|\psi\rangle$ where $|\psi\rangle$ is the initial squeezed state according to your first equation?

Okay, yes that is correct. My problem is that I was also applying $e^{-2r}$ to the 2nd term, which comes from the vacuum state. It is only applied to the $\Delta\hat{X}^2_{\Theta,a,in}$ term.

So did you get the answer for your question then?

Yes I think that answers my question.
